# How do I apply an ActionListener to the body of an applet?

Tags: java, applet, actionlistener

I would like to implement mouse and keyboard listeners on the entire area an applet occupies.

I want to use strictly Java 1.1's input event methods, because I have a computer that hates Java 1.0's input methods and doesn't have anything newer than 1.1 installed.

What syntax of "addActionListener(this);" (or something related to handleEvents) should I use?

Comment: It would be cheaper to buy one new computer, than support a '1.1 compatible' project on 10 other computers.

Comment: I disagree. I know there is a really simple solution. After all, RuneScape and a million other Java developers do this.

Comment: *"After all, RuneScape ..do this."*  If you mean 'support 1.1' then this [support page](http://www.runescape.com/kbase/guid/the_game_won_t_load) of the RuneScape site suggests otherwise. E.G. *"Upgrade Java."* & *"try changing the Java setting to 'Force Sun Java'"* (which excludes the MSVM - the one VM that people wanted to hold on to, years after its shelf life).  Making up stuff will not change the fact that supporting older JREs does not make economic sense.

Comment: Economic sense? Have you lost your marbles? This so called "MSVM" is exactly what I'm referring to. There is obviously potential for me to sell my software, but I'm not a developer. I've got other things to do. Anyways, how do you go about implementing those elusive mouse and keyboard listeners?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to keep it strictly Java 1.1 (no Java 1.0 or Java 1.2+).

You might want to supply justifications for this desire since it severely limits what you can do, and forces you to use a long non-supported version of Java.

> Do I need to implement ActionListener on my main class?

No, and you *never* need to do this, nor should you ever do this.

> What syntax of "addActionListener(this);" should I use?

You can't add an ActionListener to an entire applet. Perhaps you want to use a keylistener instead, but I'm not sure as your question is a bit short on details.

Comment: I updated the first post. By "using Java 1.1" I'm only referring to the input methods, not the libraries in general. By "the entire applet" I'm talking about the lowest-level component I can legally reference that covers the screen area of the whole applet.

Comment: @Anon: you still give no justification for your restrictions. Why? Is it a state secret?

Comment: And again: your problem has nothing to do with use of ActionListeners. ActionListeners deal with buttons and menus, that's it.

Comment: No, no. It's just a compatibility thing. I have a computer that for whatever reason hates Java 1.0's input methods, but doesn't have anything newer than Java 1.1 installed.

Comment: If I can't use ActionListener, then what should I use that supports the mouse?

Comment: Surely you've looked this question up on line and in tutorials and books before asking here right? If you did you'd run across MouseListener, right? I'm not criticizing your lack of knowledge -- we all have to start with no knowledge, but having and showing initiative helps.

Comment: I have, in fact, but I can't remember it for the life of me, and "traditional" Java 1.0 mouse events (like the kind you'd find in JavaScript) don't work, at least not for me. I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I just want to set up some events to change some variables.